# On AWS EKS, how can I update an addon multiple minor versions at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, eks, upgrade

Some enabled add-on lags far behind the latest version.
The add-on is NOT self-managed (checked using [the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-vpc-cni.html#vpc-add-on-create) with `aws eks describe-addon`)

[image]

That specific addon has no compatibility issues between the current and latest versions for the cluster.

Am I forced to manually click on each minor version and wait?